# In android studio, how to open multiple projects in one window?

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I am trying out google's android studio. In eclipse, I can open multiple projects under one window. Is that a way to do this in android studio?

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html) and then there may be an answer [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5248553?tstart=0)

Answer (score 5):

That is not true. A project in IDEA is not like a workspace. 
Think about this: you set the minSDK, target and maxSDK to the project, it has some configuration for the project. But the workspace dont have any configuration.

The project is just a project, but can have multiple packages like in eclipse. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can open Multiple Projects in a single Environment

Step1:
Go to your project Settings.gradle File

Step2:

```
`include ':projectName'`

project(':projectName').projectDir = new File(rootDir, '../projectPath')
```

Step3:
Sync gradle file

Comment: And then in Projects window change the view type to "Project". Both the folders will be listed here. Thanks, it works for me.

Comment: I don't know, how and whom is going to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible, android studio is based on intelij and intelij open one and only one project or multi-module project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

According to the Eclipse to Intellij FAQ: 
- Projects in intellij = workspaces in eclipse.
- Modules in intellij = projects in eclipse.

There seems to be somethings wrong with the new module wizards in Android Studio; at least I find them creating different types of projects, depending on what options I use (export/import creates different projects than if you build them from scratch). Migrating multiple projects to this currently looks as if it is going to be a serious pain.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is help someone. I'm looking for open several projects in one window. So, in Android studio, after you running several projects, you can go to Window -> Merge All Projects Windows. Exactly what i need.